# Comparing two dataframes and storing results in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have two data frames like this: The first has one column and 720 rows (dataframe A), the second has ten columns and 720 rows(dataframe B). The dataframes contain only numerical values.

I am trying to compare them this way: I want to go through each column of dataframe B and compare each cell(row) of that column to the corresponding row in dataframe A .
(Example: For the first column of dataframe B I compare the first row to the first row of dataframe A, then the second row of B to the second row of A etc.)

Basically I want to compare each column of dataframe B to the single column in dataframe A, row by row.

If the the value in dataframe B is smaller or equal than the value in dataframe A, I want to add +1 to another dataframe (or list, depending on how its easier). In the end, I want to drop any column in dataframe B that doesnt have at least one cell to satisfy the condition (basically if the value added to the list or new dataframe is 0).

I tried something like this (written for a single row, I was thinking of creating a for loop using this) but it doesn't seem to do what I want:

```
DfA_i = pd.DataFrame(DA.iloc[i])
DfB_j = pd.DataFrame(DB.iloc[j])
B = DfB_j.values
DfC['Criteria'] = DfA_i.apply(lambda x: len(np.where(x.values <= B)), axis=1)
dv = dt_dens.values
if dv[1] < 1:
            DF = DA.drop(i)
```

I hope I made my problem clear enough and sorry for any mistakes. Thanks for any help.

Comment: the example in quotation is not correctly worded. also it will help a great deal if you could provide a reproducible dataframe for the community to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
dfB.loc[:, dfB.ge(dfA.values).any()]
```

**Explanation**: `dfA.values` returns the numpy array with shape `(720,1)`. Then `dfB.ge(dfA.values)` check each column from `dfB` against that single column from `dfA`; this returns a boolean dataframe of same size with `dfB`. Finally `.any()` check along the columns of that boolean dataframe for any `True`.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(A.to_numpy() <= B.to_numpy(),1,np.nan), columns=B.columns, index=A.index).dropna(how='all')
```

you and replace the `np.nan` in the `np.where` condition with whatever values you wish, including keeping the original values of `dataframe 'B'`